# Downloading blob file on JDBC causes memory leak if internet is cutoff during preparedstatement.execute()

Tags: java, mysql, download, garbage-collection, blob

i am trying to make a robust application that can download  blob files from a mysql server. The files are executables or other binary files.
The download itself works well, but i want to bullet proof it to survive an internet cutoff midway in a download.
If the internet cutoff occurs before the preparedstatement.execute(),everything goes well, the memory is cleared of garbage and the program exits gracefully .
On the other hand ,if i cutoff the internet 5 seconds into the execution of the preparedstatement.execute(),the thread that is downloading hangs indefinitely and is never cleared by the Garbage collector and the program never exits.
The main exits,the downloader manager exits,but the downloading thread never exits.
Methodology:

- (1)Main thread to trigger Downloadmanager object into existence.
- (2)Downloadermanager object trigggers a separate Puredownload
  object(in a separate thread) to invoke prepared statement to get
  binary data to make downloads.
- (3)Downloadermanager  polls    PureDownload object to detect if a
  cutoff connection has caused it to    become unresponsive and tries
  to kill it.

Observing from heap dump on netbeans, a puredownload object that has been cutoff midway in a preparestatement never gets garbage collected,and waits indefinitely
I have tried all possible ways :

- (1)Thread.isinterrupted() to close the puredownload object and get it
  to be GCed.
- (2)CLose all resultset,statements,connections in separate try catch
  but they never het triggered.
- (3)Place a try catch around the preparedstatement.executequery in the
  hope the failed internet connection will make it throw an exception
  and be able to close all remaining objects and exit. no success.
- (4)Outputstream.close() and inputsream.close()
- (5)inputstream.read(buffer) is placed in a thread.interrupted() while
  loop.

and many other combinations to get it to respond to a closed internet connection midway during the download.
I ahve failed all my trials.
ANyone has a suggestion?

///////////////////////////////////////main class/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
/*
 * this calss launches the program and outputs a counter on sysout every 1000 milliseocnds.It will create a downloader manager object in an executor.
 */

package learningthreads;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class LearningThreads {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        //the object that will run the dwonload on another thread
        downloadermanager dm = new downloadermanager();

        Future<?> wf = executor.submit(dm);


        ///just a counter on another thread to give the time when events are occuring..it will just ouput numbers on sys out,together with other messages from other threads. 

        executor.submit(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){



                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("the time is " + i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(LearningThreads.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }


            }


        });



        executor.shutdown();



    }

}
//////////////////////////////////end of main class////////////////////////////////////////////////








    //////////////////////////////////////////////////downloader manager class/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /*
     * thhis object will manage and monitor a puredownload object .Its responsibility if to keep track of what the puredownload object is doing,and kill it if necessary when the latter has become unresponsive.
     *In this test, it tries to kill the duredownload object after 15 seconds as the puredownload object takes around 5-10 seconds to connect,and the preparedstatement.execute() is in full operation after 15 seconds.
     *so this is the best time to cut off the internet and see what happens.
     */

    package learningthreads;

    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    /**
     *
     * @author DELL PC
     */
    public class downloadermanager implements Callable{
        PureDownload PDS;
        Thread T;
        int memoryint=0;
        int deadbeatcounter=0;
        private volatile boolean running=true;


        downloadermanager(){    
        PDS=new PureDownload();
        T=new Thread(PDS);
        T.start();
        }





        @Override
        public Object call(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);          
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


           kill();




            return null;
        }

        //after various ways of trying to kill the puredownload object, as a last resort ,here i cam trying to kill the thread forcefully without any good practice of terminating a thread,as the puredwonload object refuses any attempt to be garbage collected.
        public void kill(){
            try {

                System.out.println("kill");

                Thread f = T;
                Method m = Thread.class.getDeclaredMethod( "stop0" , new Class[]{Object.class} );
                m.setAccessible( true );
                m.invoke( f , new ThreadDeath() );
                System.out.println("end kill");
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(downloadermanager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////end of downloadermanagerclass/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////puredownload class////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
    *This is the object that does the actual download.
    *everything works fine.The problem is it refuses to exit gracefully and be garbage collected if an internet cutoff occurs 5 seconds after the preparedstatement is executing.
    *all standard methods to cut off and close all obejcts have been tried ,in various combinations .
    */

    package learningthreads;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;



    public class PureDownload implements Callable,Runnable {

        String dbname = "SMSVerautoDB";
        String connectionString = "jdbc:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com:3306/" + dbname;
        String username = "xxxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxx";
        String filename = "file.exe";
        String outputpath = "C:\\xxxxxx";
        Connection conn;
        InputStream input;
        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private volatile int counter=0;
        downloadermanager dm;

        ResultSet rs = null;PreparedStatement pstmt;    

        public void stop() {        
            //this function tries to kill the object from memory as it is not responding 
            //various attempts have been made here as well to have a stopping method to set flags etc.
            //setting all as null is just one example
            System.out.println("puredownload.stop.58");
            rs=null;
            pstmt=null;
            conn=null;
            System.out.println(" puredownload.stop.64");      
        }

        public Void call() throws Exception {

            //this function executes if i am using executor
            download();
             return null;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this function executes if i am using thread        
            download();
        }



       public void download(){
       // update sql
            String selectSQL = "SELECT xxxxx FROM xxxxx WHERE x=?";
            try {           
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

                // set parameter;
                pstmt.setString(1, filename);
                System.out.println("physically remove internet connection in 5 seconds when you see this message");

                try {
                    //pstmt.setQueryTimeout(2);
                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                } catch (Exception E) {
                    System.out.println("trying to get an exception from exceute query here,when connection is cut off" + E.getMessage());
                    //pstmt.cancel();
                }
                // write binary stream into file

                String outputpath_2 = outputpath + filename;
                File file = new File(outputpath_2);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                while (rs.next()) {

                    input = rs.getBinaryStream("Logiciel");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

                    while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {                      
                            output.write(buffer);
                    }

                }
            } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(PureDownload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);           
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PureDownload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {       

            }



       }





    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////end of puredownload class///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: You are actually using a dbms with internet in between?

Comment: You don't seem to be closing you database resources when you're done with them (or on error). Do some research into try-with-resources for some ideas into how to make you're life easier. There is a reason why Thread.stop is deprecated. You should be using flags/locks and the Thread's interrupted state to manage the running state instead

Comment: Your problem is very jdbc driver specific. What driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you use the driver mysql provides, you can define the timeout of socket connections as a parameter of your jdbc url.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> socketTimeout
>
> Timeout on network socket operations (0, the default means no timeout).
>   Default: 0
>
> Since version: 3.0.1

Since the default is to wait indefinitely, try to set it to 10 secs.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets the same issue,
The defect was a socket timeout should have been specified by appending

"?socketTimeout=10000" to the connection string.
i chose 10 seconds.